# Ошибка в куками в php(Symfony)

Tags: php, cookie, symfony

Дело обстоит так.

```
$cookie = new Cookie('nameCookie',
                     'ValueCookies',
                     strtotime("+1 day")
                    );
$response = new Response();
$response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
$response->send();
```

и после этого у меня дальнейшие действия не выполняются. 
Даже шаблон не рендерится(((
 а вот и ошибка что пишется в консоли.

```
|CRITI| REQUES Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: 
"Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "" at line 0." at 
/home/pc/dev_/bibi/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php line 152
```

а это уже конд в symfony на который ссылается ошибка

```
 if (filter_var(ini_get('session.use_cookies'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) && headers_sent($file, $line)) {
     throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "%s" at line %d.', $file, $line));
 }
```

---

```
public function SocNetwork($socNetwork, Request $request)
    {   
        $cookie = new Cookie('socNetCookie',
                            $socNetwork,
                            strtotime("+1 day")
                        );
        $response = new Response();
        $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
        $response->send();
        dump($response);
        return $this->render('home/index.html.twig');
    }
```

Comment: У вас где-то выводится текст перед заголовком, покажите полностью ваш `action`

Comment: добавил ответом на свой вопрос иначе код непонятен все в кучу, куки сохраняются все хорошо, но после $response->send() все встает. уже все перепробовал. Осваиваю symfony и встречаюсь с такими ошибками уже голова кругом.

Answer (score 1):

`$response->send()` возвращает ответ. `$this->render('home/index.html.twig')` тоже автоматически генерирует ответ и он возвращается из контроллера. Из-за этого возникает ошибка, т.к. заголовки ответа уже были отправлены.
Изменить поведение, при котором метод render генерирует свой Response можно передав ему объект класса Response в качестве третьего аргумента.

Код action можно изменить так:

```
public function SocNetwork($socNetwork, Request $request)
{   
        $cookie = new Cookie(
              'socNetCookie',
              $socNetwork,
              strtotime("+1 day")
        );

        $response = new Response();
        $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);

        return $this->render('home/index.html.twig', [], $response);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я и не знал как это исправить хотя все понимал.